# C# DataContractJsonSerializer ReadObject not throwing error if member is missing

Tags: c#, json, serialization, datacontractjsonserializer

I have a user class like

```
public class User
{
  public string UserName {get;set;}
  public string Application {get;set;}
}
```

Now, I am using it like

```
var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(User));
var objApp = (User)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(JsonInput)));
```

But my JSON JsonInput doesn't contain both values for example Application is not available in the JSON. This still serializes with on only UserName.
The JSON and class above is an example, there are quite a few members for me to check them individually ! 
I want to make sure, the JSON contains all the members of the class, if not , throw error.

But I can't seem to find way. What am I missing here?

Comment: if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(objApp.Application))

Comment: @Milney : The JSON and class is an example, there are quite a few members for me to check them individually !

Comment: To the 'downvoter'. Rather than downvoting, please care to explain /comment why downvote? What could I have done better to explain the issue to seek the help?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Newtonsoft (which you can install with **Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json**) - You can set the **MissingMemberHandling** property of the settings;

```
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
```

Then pass it;

```
    var userObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jsonInput, settings);
```

If you must use Datacontract instead, you can decorate your User object with required attributes;

```
 [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
 public string? RequiredProperty { get; set; }
```

Comment: Newtonsoft is pretty much the default json serialiser now. Even Microsoft use it internally. Your much better off switching to this and forgetting the DataContractJsonSerializer ever existed

Comment: ^ This. There is no reason to prefer the DataContract one, but I put it there just in case as I know some projects can have weird constraints @S

Comment: If you want to apply `[DataMember]` to members, it's also necessary to apply `[DataContract]` to the type itself, which makes serialization opt-in rather than opt-out.

Comment: ^ Indeed, sorry forgot about that as I do not use it much

Comment: @Milney Thanks for both points and detailed explanation. I am away from my work machine at the moment. Will check tomorrow and update you.